# Building apps for clients, our dev account or set them one up?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, iphone-developer-program

I am still trying to get my head around this.  So far we have produced in house apps for ourselves under a single developer licence but now some of our clients are requesting apps.

Correct me if I am wrong but there are two ways to approach this.

1. App is developed under our dev account for the client, client trusts us to send them sales trends and any income from their apps.  Client has no access to iTunes Connect (as all our other apps are on there).
2. We get the client to create their own Developer Account with Apple, setup their own banking then send us the team leader login details so that we can produce apps under their details.  I imagine some amount of trust has to be accepted here as we can see the client banking details and possibly their original iTunes login details?  I also imagine that we should setup different workstation logins specifically for each client project so that any keychain data is kept separate from other accounts.

Have I got this right?

Many thanks for help.

Geoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, sounds right to me, except you won't need the login details if the client can provide you with the provisioning profiles. Your option 1 wouldn't realistically be feasible imho.

Of course there is also the B2B Apple program which might fit your needs:

http://images.apple.com/business/docs/ASVPP_Business_Guide_US.pdf

"Businesses can work with third-party app developers and business partners to procure these custom B2B apps securely and privately through the program."

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 would be most tedious because it would mean that you have to tabulate their profits for them on a weekly basis in a spreadsheet. Apple's sales reporting pages are surprisingly simplistic as compared to e.g. Google's so I think this would give you some agony and make you wonder why why why are we doing it this way.

How about an Option 3, in which you send them the source code and have their iOS person (assuming they have one) build and distribute the binary?

Comment: I recently developed an iPhone app for a client and we went with "Option 3". I was a Team Member for them so I was able to get the necessary certificates and provisioning profiles. I sent them the final project and resources so they could build and upload it themselves. That worked out pretty well for us.

Answer (score 0):

Best option is both have their individual apple developer accounts.

Make an **xarchive** using your account and send that to client and client can make ipa out of xarchive with their signers(cert and provisioning profile)

FYI:

Let the client know your **bundle id** and **entitlements** of the app so that they can create matching provisioning profile in their member center account.

and ask them to change the team id found in application identitifer in entitlements.plist manualy